# xgboost gives negative R2

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, non-linear-regression

I am just trying a basic example on the Boston dataset. Negative `R2` means it's performing worse than just returning the average, I wonder if I am doing something wrong, or how can it perform so badly in sample? How do I fix this?

```
xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror', colsample_bytree=0.3, learning_rate = 0.1,
                max_depth=5, alpha=10, n_estimators=10)
xg_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_train_hat = xg_reg.predict(X_train)
train_r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred=y_train_hat)
train_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_hat))
print (train_r2, train_rmse, y_train.mean(), y_train_hat.mean())

-0.11469938481461228 10.091020035258527 22.59630606860158 14.59753
```

Using random forest for example, I was able to get R2=94% in sample and 76% out of sample, so I know I am doing something wrong with xgboost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have taken `n_estimators` value as `10` which is very small. The default value is 100.

Default settings of `xgboost` is quite strong enough to provide you the best result. You don't need to manually select the parameters.  Just do

```
 xgb.XGBRegressor()
```

Better way to choose the parameters is through `hyperparameter tuning` which you can do using grid search.

Well after hyperaparameter tuning I found the best value of `n_estimator = 1000` with `max_depth = 4`.